# formulario no envía datos por el método POST en el servidor

Tags: php

He creado un pequeño login para iniciar sesión. Es de lo más simple que hay, en local me funciona bien, pero la sorpresa que me encuentro es que en el servidor los datos no se envían.

```html
<?php

session_start();

require 'admin/config.php';


if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $errores = "";
  if ($usuario == $usuario_admin AND $password == $password_admin) {
     $_SESSION['administrador'] = $usuario;
     //header("Location: " . $ruta . "admin.php");
  } else {
     $errores = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
  }
}

?>



<div style="width:100%;max-width:1000px;margin:auto;margin-top:20px;" class="wrapper">

    <p style="width:100%;background:#2c3e50;padding:5px;text-align:center;color:white;">INICIO DE SESIÓN</p>
    <form autocomplete="off" style="padding:10px;background:#f2f2f2;" class="" action="http://localhost/bebidasexoticas/login.php" method="post">
        <input style="" type="text" name="usuario" value="" placeholder="Usuario:" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Contraseña:" autocomplete="off">
                    <p style="margin-bottom:10px;background:#FFBEBE;color:#DA2222;border:1px solid #DA2222;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 10px;">Usuario o contraseña incorrectos</p>
                <input class="btn-enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Iniciar Sesión">
    </form>

</div>
```

No se me ocurre nada, he probado tanto con `isset($_POST['enviar'])` como con `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` pero sigo en las mismas. Incomprensiblemente en local me funciona, en el servidor no se me envían los datos.

Las credenciales que se cargan del fichero config.php se cargan bien.

Comment: No sera por que en el action tienes quemado action="http://localhost/bebidasexoticas/login.php", quizas localhost en el servidor en donde estas desplegando no sera resuelto a la ip de la maquina.

Comment: En `action='...` deja solo la ruta del archivo, si este está en la misma carpeta que tu HTML con que dejes algo como `action='login.php'` no es necesario incluír localhost

Comment: El problema debe der en esta parte action="http://localhost/bebidasexoticas/login.php", estas incluyendo localhost en la ruta y obviamente en el servidor no puede encontrar localhost , puedes dejarlo así nomas **action='bebidasexoticas/login.php'** o claro, depende del nivel de ubicación de tu archivo **login.php**

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba si el require apunta al lugar correcto en el servidor, aunque apuntara bien en local.
En el action del form cambia la dirección de localhost por la del servidor actual (cuidado con los niveles de directorios).
Si no te funcionara (como plan b), intenta hacerlo con get en vez de con post (por ejemplo con algunos diseños como Bootstrap, los botones no funcionan con post).
Espero que te funcione.